# How to properly refresh the page after the update div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I make the content update when I click on the link.

**Script**

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "history.js/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js"> </script>
//download: https://codeload.github.com/browserstate/history.js/legacy.zip/master
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function(){

        $('.sidebar a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var linkLocation = $(this).attr('href');            
            History.pushState(null, document.title, linkLocation);

        return false;
        });

        function loadPage(url) {            
            $('.content').load(url);
        }


        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            var History = window.History;
            History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var State = History.getState();

                loadPage(State.url);

            });
        });
    });


</script>
```

**Html**

```
...
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="page1.html" > № 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="page2.html" > № 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="page3.html" > № 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="page4.html" > № 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="page5.html" > № 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="page6.html" > № 6</a></li>
    </ul>
...
</div> 
<div class="content"></div>
</div></body>
```

**Page1.html**

```
    ...
    <body>
    <h1>№ 1</h1>
    <p>lalalal</p>
    <br>
    <form action =select.php method=get>    
            <div align=center>bla-bla-bla<input type=text name=param1> <br><br>
                <table border=0 width=80%>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td align=center> <input type=reset   value="Clear" > </td>
                            <td align=center>  <input type=submit name=send value="Send">   </td> 
                            <td align=center> <input type="button" onClick="history.back();" value="Back"/> </td>
                        </tr>  
                    </tbody>   
                </table>     
      </div>  
    </form> 

</body>
```

When you click on the link, the contents of the div change, and the URL changes in the address bar (for example on `mysite.com / page1.html`), but if you refresh the page, the browser, of course, refers directly to the file`page1.html`. I was looking for a solution on the Internet, it seems that in this situation I need to use a hash, but I still do not understand how this should work. I ask for help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Hashes are probably the better way to go (or query strings). That's because with your current approach, you will need your server to intercept the request for `page1.html` and actually redirect it to the index page instead. By using query strings and hashes, you can use JS to read the values from there and decide which state to set your page to, when the user loads (e.g. from refreshing) the page.

Comment: @Terry, the problem is that I can not figure out how to implement it)) Examples of similar solutions to this problem did not help me.